# How to simulate infinite number of elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a custom slider, since none of those I tried are good for my current needs ;-)

For now, I have a simple code that scrolls elements, but I want it to be circular, eg. when I hit the last slide, to append the first one and treat that slide as next one.

My code is as follows:

JavaScript

```
    var cont = $('.newslider'),
        els = cont.children('.inner').children('img').length,
        width = cont.find('img').width(),
        total = els * width,
        margin = ($(window).outerWidth(true) - width)/2;


    cont.find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).css('float','left');
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 37) {
            cont.children('.inner').animate({
                "left": "-="+margin
            });
        } else if(e.which === 39) {
            cont.children('.inner').animate({
                "left": "+="+margin
            });
        }
    });

    cont.on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('.inner').animate({
            "left": "-="+margin
        });
    });

    cont.css({
        'width':$(window).outerWidth(true),
        'overflow':'hidden'
    });

    cont.children('.inner').css({
        'width':total,
        'position':'relative',
        'overflow':'hidden',
        'left':'-'+margin+'px'
    });
```

HTML

```
        <section class="newslider">
            <div class="inner">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6sgoLfh/

---

Updated code thanks to @Bojan Petrovski

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7scejv/

```
        var parent = '.newslider';
        var element = 'div';

        var slideCount = $(parent).find(element).length,
            slideWidth = $(parent).find(element).width(),
            sliderWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

        var wind = $(window).outerWidth(true),
            slider = 960,
            margin = ((parseInt(wind) - parseInt(slider))/2);


        $(parent).css({ width: slideWidth, left: -margin*4 });
        $(parent).children('.inner').css({ 'width': sliderWidth, 'margin':'0 '+margin+'px'});
        $(parent).children('.inner').find(element+':last-child').prependTo(parent +' .inner');
        $(parent).children('.inner').find(element+':first-child').appendTo(parent +' .inner');

        function hightlightSlide() {
            $(parent).children('.inner').find(element).each(function(){
                //console.log($(this).offset().left+'  --  '+$(this).attr('data-id')+' --- '+margin/3);
                $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
                if(margin/3 === $(this).offset().left) {
                    $(this).addClass('active-slide');
                }
            });
        };

        function moveLeft() {
            $(parent).children('.inner').stop().animate({
                left: + slideWidth/2
            }, 500, function () {
                $(parent).children('.inner').find(element+':last-child').prependTo(parent +' .inner');
                $(parent).children('.inner').css('left', '');
                hightlightSlide();
            });
        };

        function moveRight() {
            $(parent).children('.inner').stop().animate({
                left: - slideWidth/2
            }, 500, function () {
                $(parent).children('.inner').find(element+':first-child').appendTo(parent +' .inner');
                $(parent).children('.inner').css('left', '');
                hightlightSlide();
            });
        };        


        $(parent).find(element).each(function() {
            $(this).css('float','left');
        });

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if(e.which === 37) {
                 moveLeft();
            } else if(e.which === 39) {
                moveRight();
            }
        });

        $(parent).css({
            'width':$(window).outerWidth(true),
            'overflow':'hidden'
        });

        $(parent).children('.inner').css({
            'width':sliderWidth,
            'position':'relative',
            'overflow':'hidden'
        });
```

Comment: I don't think what you gonna do to be wise, but in worst situation I'd just set scroll to top, because user would now this is not new content, but restarts the slider

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution http://jsfiddle.net/u6sgoLfh/6/ for infinite slider

```
var slideCount = $('.newslider .inner img').length;
var slideWidth = $('.newslider .inner img').width();
var slideHeight = $('.newslider .inner img').height();
var sliderWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
var margin = ($(window).outerWidth(true) - slideWidth)/2;

$('.newslider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('.newslider .inner').css({ width: sliderWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('.newslider .inner img:last-child').prependTo('.newslider .inner');

function moveLeft() {
    $('.newslider .inner').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('.newslider .inner img:last-child').prependTo('.newslider .inner');
        $('.newslider .inner').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('.newslider .inner').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('.newslider .inner img:first-child').appendTo('.newslider .inner');
        $('.newslider .inner').css('left', '');
    });
};        


    $('.newslider').find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).css('float','left');
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 37) {
             moveLeft();
        } else if(e.which === 39) {
            moveRight()
        }
    });

    $('.newslider').on('click', function() {
         moveLeft();
    });

    $('.newslider').css({
        'width':$(window).outerWidth(true),
        'overflow':'hidden'
    });

    $('.newslider').children('.inner').css({
        'width':sliderWidth,
        'position':'relative',
        'overflow':'hidden',
        'left':'-'+margin+'px'
    });
```

Comment: Great, but when going to the left (`moveLeft`) element is prepended after the animation is complete, how to prevent this?

Comment: You want the element to prepend before the animation starts? If that is the case you can simply move the line $('.newslider .inner img:last-child').prependTo('.newslider .inner'); before the animation start.

Comment: It's no use, since then it adds an element in the middle.

Comment: In my fiddle it doesn't add an element in the middle. See this http://jsfiddle.net/u6sgoLfh/8/

Comment: Yes, but I need to start from the first slide and I need to center he slide exactly. Upadted code in the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with to start from the first slide and to center it? Slider starts with the first slide, move left and the last image is prepended before the first one, and move right the first image respectively is appended at the end, and they are all the same dimensions so they are all centered( positioned ) the same

Comment: I need to have first slide (with `1` on it) in the middle, last slide (with `6`) on the left and secoun (`2`) on the right.

Comment: Well if you check the html the slider starts with the  img 1 in the middle, left is 6 right is 2. http://i.imgur.com/DPsIkO1.jpg?1